# dotCMS Plugin Development

Tags: java, plugins, dotcms

I have to develop a plugin for dotCMS. The problem is there is not a lot of information about plugin development in dotCMS' site.

In their site they say a good way to start is to look at the example plugin and start from there, but I find it complicated.

I was hoping that someone here would give me an idea of where to start, something like a brief tutorial about the plugins structure, languages, integration with dotCMS and that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few pointers. I hope this helps:

1. dotCMS has a chapter on their documentation site about developing plugins for dotCMS 1.9. You can find it here: http://dotcms.com/docs/1.9/DevelopmentAndPlugins.
2. On the dotCMS plugins page there are a few plugins available that you can download and deploy: http://dotcms.com/plugins/index.dot.

Comment: I came across that information you put in your answer, unfortunately is not explicit enough. There's no tutorial for begginers or something like that and the reason is they don't give that kind of support to open source clients (That's what one of their representatives told me).

I had to install the hello world plugin and start messing around with it so I could understand how it works.

Thanks anyway!